# Is it possible to play mp4 file, located inside Download folder on Android WebView via Video Tag?

Tags: android, html, video, local, mp4

We have Android device. Inside that device, on internal flash is located Download folder and inside that folder resides **cat.mp4**

Currently we are using following **script**:

```
<video width="365" height="200" autoplay loop controls autobuffer>
  <source src="file:///sdcard/Download/cat.mp4" type='video/mp4'> 
</video>
```

We have also tried following **script**:

```
<video width="365" height="200" src="file:///sdcard/Download/cat.mp4" autoplay loop controls autobuffer> 
</video>
```

Both scripts do not play local video file.

The html file itself, which contains above video tags, comes from certain remote location (not local).

(If we place **cat.mp4** on remote location it plays without any problem)

Is this correct approach to play local `mp4` files in WebView?
If not, which part of the code is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct approach to play local `mp4` files in WebView?

Nope you can't do that in general (webView or not). Security measures (in HTML protocols) do not allow a web-based application to access a user's files from their hard drive (or other storage).

The user must allow access by selecting the file themselves (hence the **browse/select file** option in some websites). Only options are:

- Put HTML and video files online (load everything from web)
- Put HTML in SD card's download folder then you can use `src="cat.mp4"`

A side issue with your approach begs the question, what happens for site visitors without these files on SD card? Or worse a user not even using Android (on a Win PC how can my browser make sense of `src="file:///sdcard/Download/cat.mp4"` ?)

Comment: This may not be the most elegant solution, but this is my workaround: I have installed some lightweight server on device. I upload my file  on that server and refer to it like this: src="localhost:[some port]/cat.mp4" I also changed video format, now i use webm format, because  some mp4 files did not play on my device.

Comment: Is this something that only needs to work on YOUR device (no outside internet users) but displayed via browser? So why not go with my **option 2**? Make a folder on your SD card called **mySite** and put the html file and video file there. Then the html's video tag just access `src="cat.mp4"` or `src="cat.webm"` (notice there are no folder paths?). A local html file must access files in same location.

Comment: Yes, but my html file resides on another server, i can not put it inside Download folder. I also tried to reference local (html) file via iframe tag ('src' attribute) inside my web page, but this did not work either